# Azure ARM templates - empty values as a parameters, IF function

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-rm-template

I am preparing ARM template for "Schedule update deployment" in Update Management service. I want to add parameters like: `"excludedKbNumbers"` and `"includedKbNumbers"`. I am deploying my templates using powershell. When I am passing KB numbers using mentioned parameters templates completed successfully. In case when I am putting KB number using one of the mentioned parameters, second is empty, template completed successfully. Problem is when I dont want to pass Included/Exluded KB numbers, in my powershell deployment command I am not putting parameter names  `"excludedKbNumbers"` and `"includedKbNumbers"`, and then I am receiving below error: `"message": "{\"Message\":\"The request is invalid.\",\"ModelState\":{\"softwareUpdateConfiguration.properties.updateConfiguration\":[\"Software update configuration has same KbNumbers in 
includedKbNumbers and excludedKbNumbers.\"]}}"`

I am using this structure in my template `json('null')` and this is a problematic area.
extract from my template:

```
    "parameters": {
        "excludedKbNumbers": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify excluded KB numbers, required data structure: 123456"
            }
        },
        "includedKbNumbers": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify included KB numbers, required data structure: 123456"
            }
   },
"resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/softwareUpdateConfigurations",
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-15-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('automationAccountName'), '/', parameters('scheduleName'))]",
            "properties": {
                "updateConfiguration": {
                    "operatingSystem": "[parameters('operatingSystem')]",
                    "windows": {
                        "includedUpdateClassifications": "[parameters('Classification')]",
                        "excludedKbNumbers": [
                            "[if(empty(parameters('excludedKbNumbers')), json('null'), parameters('excludedKbNumbers'))]"
                        ],
                        "includedKbNumbers": [
                            "[if(empty(parameters('includedKbNumbers')), json('null'), parameters('includedKbNumbers'))]"
                        ],
                        "rebootSetting": "IfRequired"
                    },
                    "targets": {
                        "azureQueries": [
                            {
                                "scope": [
                                    "[concat('/subscriptions', '/', parameters('subscriptionID'))]"
                                ],
                                "tagSettings": {
                                    "tags": {
                                        "[parameters('tagKey')]": [
                                            "[parameters('tagValue')]"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "filterOperator": "All"
                                },
                                "locations": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "duration": "PT2H"
                },
                "tasks": {},
                "scheduleInfo": {
                    "isEnabled": false,
                    "startTime": "2050-03-03T13:10:00+01:00",
                    "expiryTime": "2050-03-03T13:10:00+01:00",
                    "frequency": "OneTime",
                    "timeZone": "Europe/Warsaw"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
```

Comment: ugh, whats the point of not including and not excluding any KB?

Comment: I can specify required updates using this property in my template --> ```"includedUpdateClassifications": "[parameters('Classification')]",```, included/excluded KB updates is for including or excluding for example one specific KB, like KB123456. It worke like "Install all excepf of KB123456."

Comment: @4c74356b41 -  any ideas how to fix that issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try doing this:

```
"excludedKbNumbers": "[if(empty(parameters('excludedKbNumbers')), json('null'), array(parameters('excludedKbNumbers')))]",
"includedKbNumbers": "[if(empty(parameters('includedKbNumbers')), json('null'), array(parameters('includedKbNumbers')))]"
```

Comment: It worked, I corrected my template as per your suggestions, great, thanks a lot!!!